# Delete Specific Instance of A Class

Tags: jquery, class, object, if-statement

There has got to be a more efficient way of doing this. I have the following code

```
if(isOverlap("#mainCharacter", "#objID") == true) {
    $("#objID").remove();
}
```

which removes the specific object, but each object has to have different IDs and if statements for it to work correctly. I want it to have a class parameter but remove only the one object that overlaps. Is there something like `$(this.".classID").remove();` that will do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very near to it. You an pass this as a [context with your selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) or use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method on this to find elements statisfying the selector in the descendants.

```
$(this.".classID").remove();
```

To

```
$(".classID", this).remove();
```

or

```
$(this).find(".classID").remove();
```

Comment: Makes sense, but it isn't working for me for some reason. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jh7LD/9/) is my project, the function is found at the very bottom of the JavaScript section. I know it is passing the if statement because it counts the coins, any idea why it is not removing? Is it something wrong with my HTML?

Comment: You do not have this avaiable there I am afraid. If it is so pass the required element right from where you start calling function.

Comment: So because the function is not run upon load I cannot have contextual removal?

Comment: Its not about when you run but how it get run. Add a parameter to function and pass current object from the function from where to initiate call.